# How to remove specific string between two substrings from given string in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove some part of text in the given string. So the problem is as follows. I have a string. Say HTML code like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {background-color: powderblue;}
    h1   {color: blue;}
    p    {color: red;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want the code to remove all the css related code. i.e. the string should now look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried that with this function in python:

```
def css_remover(text):
    m = re.findall('<style>(.*)</style>$', text,re.DOTALL)
    if m:
        for eachText in text.split(" "):
            for eachM in m:
                if eachM in  eachText:
                    text=text.replace(eachText,"")
                    print(text)
```

But this doesn't work. I want the function to handle spaces, newline character so that it removes everything in between `<style> </style>` tag. Also, I hope if any word is attached to the tag, they aren't affected. Like 
`hello<style> klasjdklasd </style>>` should yield `hello>`

Comment: try to change `findall` with `sub`

Comment: @Tomerikoo it doesnt work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the `$` which means end of string. try this:

```
x = re.sub('<style>.*?</style>', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(x)
```

You can check out [this website](https://regex101.com/r/Fti1aD/1), has a nice regex demo.

**A little note**: I am not extremely familiar with CSS so if there are nested `<style>` tags it might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note particularly the `?` character in the `<style>(.*?)</style>` portion of the RegExp expression so as not to be "too greedy". Otherwise, in the example below, it would also remove the `<title>` HTML tag.

```
import re

text = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {background-color: powderblue;}
    h1   {color: blue;}
    p    {color: red;}
    </style>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    body {background-color: powderblue;}
    h1   {color: blue;}
    p    {color: red;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

  </body>
</html>
"""

regex = re.compile(r' *<style>(.*?)</style> *\n?', re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
text = regex.sub('', text, 0)

print (text == """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

  </body>
</html>
""")
```

Comment: What's the difference from my answer? not to mention that ` *` and ` *\n` should be replaced with `\s`

Comment: @Tomerikoo: If you replace ` *` with `\s*` you end up with `<head><title>Test</title></head>`, i.e. you are deleting newlines you probably do not want to delete. Now you might want to use instead `[ \t]*`, so you handle tab characters also. But in reality, there is no end to what you could be looking for on the same line to replace such as a comment: `  <!-- my style: --> <style>`. So I was just assuming that the file was using simple spaces. Compare your output with mine. I try to delete the whole line if it only contains the tag and spaces.